# Memory management with NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I found an answer to this a while ago, and made a mental note to fix it, but now I can't for the life of me find the post again.

Very simple - my current method for adding dictionaries to an array is leaky. Please, what is the best way to ensure they are being released properly? My method:

```
[beachPresenters addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"Kayak rides",@"name",@"kayak_sm.png",@"smPhoto",@"kayak_med",@"medPhoto",@"Free kayak rides for kids",@"description",@"",@"Friday",
                                @"All day! 10.00am - 6.00pm",@"Saturday",@"",@"Sun",@"Beach",@"stage",@"Blah blah blah",@"blurb",nil]];
```

Comment: A solid understanding of the [memory management rules](http://tinyurl.com/42kbr33) would have helped you answer this yourself. Basically, you're allocating something without releasing it.

Comment: Thank you Caleb and, yes, I'm sure that when I have a solid understanding of memory management issues, I will be able to answer my own questions. This may lead my wife to wonder why I'm talking to myself, but that's another issue.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`beachPresenters` (I assume it's an array) takes ownership of the dictionary, so the +1 to the reference count caused by `+alloc/-init` of the dictionary is not balanced. Thus, the dictionary is leaked.

Use the convenience method equivalent to balance the retain:

```
NSDictionary *presenter = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: ...];
[beachPresenters addObject: presenter];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array beachPresenters retains the mutable array you created, but your array as created in your example already has a retain count of one. So even if you dispose of beachPresenters, your dictionary will still be retained, i.e., leaked.

Use [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:] instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can have implementation like below:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"Kayak rides",@"name",@"kayak_sm.png",@"smPhoto",@"kayak_med",@"medPhoto",@"Free kayak rides for kids",@"description",@"",@"Friday",
                             @"All day! 10.00am - 6.00pm",@"Saturday",@"",@"Sun",@"Beach",@"stage",@"Blah blah blah",@"blurb",nil];

[beachPresenters addObject:dict];
[dict release];
```

or

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"Kayak rides",@"name",@"kayak_sm.png",@"smPhoto",@"kayak_med",@"medPhoto",@"Free kayak rides for kids",@"description",@"",@"Friday",
                             @"All day! 10.00am - 6.00pm",@"Saturday",@"",@"Sun",@"Beach",@"stage",@"Blah blah blah",@"blurb",nil] autorelease];
```